# I want to show some value based on database value using ignited datatable in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, datatables, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

In this code, i wil get status as value 1 or 0 from databse. i want to display active if the status value is one,else inactive.Anybody knows?

Controller

```
     public function datatable() {

            $this->datatables
                    ->select("prd_id,prd_name,status")
                    ->from('jil_products')   
 ->edit_column('status', '$1', $this->custom_status('status'));

            echo $this->datatables->generate();
        }
```

I did callback for this

```
function custom_status($val)
{
   return ($val == 1) ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';

}
```

but if the value is 1,then always return 'Inactive'. i dont knw why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 public function datatable() {
/* Option 1 when you have 2 option */   
$this->datatables
    ->select("prd_id,prd_name,IF(status = '1', 'Active', 'Inactive') as status")
    ->from('jil_products');
 /* Option 2 when you have more then 2 option */   
   $this->datatables
    ->select("prd_id,prd_name, 
    case jil_products.status
    when '1' then 'Active'
    when '2' then 'Inactive'
    when '3' then 'Suspended'
    end as status
   ")
    ->from('jil_products');
   echo $this->datatables->generate();
 }
```

Comment: its working i have one doubt. if status has values 1,2,3 and hav to diplay active,inactive,suspend.then hw wil change the code?

Comment: can you suggest any tutorial or page to study more about ignited datatables in codeigniter??

Comment: @Angel You have to be learn SQL more and try to implement in codeigniter active pattern structure..

Comment: i knw sql ,but i dnt knw how it convert into ignited table query.

Comment: So learn active patter method. see [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: did you see my new question?? i dnt knw solution is possible for that.can you check it     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35646188/i-want-to-convert-this-query-to-ignited-datatable-query-in-codeigniter?noredirect=1#comment58973144_35646188

Comment: i did active records also,but ignited queries are differnt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104617/discussion-between-yash-and-angel).